# how can I use "amdgpu" instead of "radeon" drivers on 20.04?

Tags: drivers, radeon, amdgpu

thanks for taking time to read me.

I was looking for a way to use fully my GC in blender (openCL etc.), I'm new to linux.

So I checked and my GC, which is Radeon HD 7870 GHz edition, is compatible with amdgpu drivers

```
 lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]
        Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

but, as you can see here, it's not used by default and I don't know why.

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]
       fabricant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration : driver=radeon latency=0
       ressources : irq:30 mémoire:e0000000-efffffff mémoire:f7e00000-f7e3ffff portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

I looked for solution, and I tried several things :

- blacklist radeon -> not working
- installing amdgpu and telling grub to boot with it -> lead to black screen on boot (no signal)
- installing amdgpu-pro and telling grub to boot with it -> lead to black screen on boot (no signal)

so here I am, I tried other thing that I don't remember but nothing works.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, I know, but it was my first Google hit when searching for this. So I'll leave what worked for me (Also Ubuntu 20.04 + Radeon HD 7870 GHz):

Add PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Then edit Grub: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and add the following lines to the end:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 amdgpu.modeset=1"
```

Finally, update Grub and reboot:

```
$ sudo update-grub2 && sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
$ reboot
```

Confirm with `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`.

Blacklisting radeon was not neccessary.

Comment: Thank you for this Herbert.

Running `AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT`, I have always had problems with the monitors.
What worked for me finally is following a thousand commands from the internet, but the main ones I believe:


1 - I had to downgrade to a specific Kernel version `Linux 5.13.0-27-generic`
2 - the settings you recommend here


Specifically, I think `amdgpu.modeset=1` must have been the issue, since I was getting an `VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting` error from `dmesg`