# How can i enable AMDGPU kernel driver? (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, hp, amd-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS i followed the instructions from another post: [how can I use "amdgpu" instead of "radeon" drivers on 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266616/how-can-i-use-amdgpu-instead-of-radeon-drivers-on-20-04)
But after rebooting I'm welcomed by this (see image)
[image: Console output before system freezes]

Also i can see this weird line, probably related to the kernel driver:
[image: Weird graphical glitch]

The output of the command: `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: Radeon
```

I'm certain that my APU (AMD A8-6410 APU with Radeon R5 M330) is compatible with AMDGPU because i used it in Ubuntu 20.04LTS and in other distros like PopOS, but for some reason in Ubunut 22.04LTS im having issues with it.

General laptop Specs:
[image]

Any assistance will be much appreciated (also sorry if my English is bad, I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: Hm, just an educated quess: NVIDIA driver don't work with wayland, maybe the AMD drivers don't either. You should change to a X11 Session. I described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1380838/906933) how to do it in a terminal..

Comment: Aye, but the issue is that i can't even get into the login screen, it freezes right before the gui "spawns" and neither i can get into my terminal, but imma try it.

Comment: What kernel are you using?

Comment: @David i was on Kernel 5.19 the default one, right now I'm on the 6.2 Kernel, i still have that kernel, didn't remove it as some guides say

Comment: if nvidia will not work on wayland, and I am using per echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE wayland, then why is Ubuntu giving me an option when I search for an app, eg VLC, right clicking it, launch using discrete graphics? I have manually installed drivers installed (though it does not say what in my software additional drivers field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to share a workaround for this issue, because after digging up for a bit i realized that the kernel 5.19 has issues with legacy AMD hardware (2015 and early) that tried to use the AMDGPU kernel driver which crashes your system on boot up.

What i did was simply upgrade my kernel to 6.2.9-060209-generic by following the steps shared here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1388117/236992
In my case i used the shell script and it worked:

```
rodrigoal@rodrigoal-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:~$ uname -r
6.2.9-060209-generic
```

Afterwards i edited my grub file: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

I added the following after the "quiet splash" `radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1"`

It looked like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1"
```

For my hardware is was cik because my integrated gpu is a Radeon R5 M330.

Once that was done, i saved the edit and executed the following command:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Once it finishes you reboot your PC/laptop.

Now the output of the command `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` should be like mine:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

Hope this helps anyone else who suffers from the same issue.

Comment: This is not a supported kernel and will cause issue with future upgrades.

Comment: @David Should i rollback to the 5.19 kernel?

Comment: The 5.19 is the kernel series there are updates to it all the time. So maybe there is a newer 5.19 then the one you had before. A full kernel number would be 5.19.xx

Comment: I think this is a valid solution. Thanks for sharing @Hunter_115

Comment: @David The full kernel name was: linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic, it updated from the linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic, both versions had the same issue sadly.